# Microsoft Access DoCmd.OutputTo not recognizing acOutPutQuery

Tags: powershell, ms-access, jscript

Right now, I am just working with powershell, but I plan on porting this concept to JScript and using the `.NET` jsc with `ActiveXObject('Access.Application')`. I have opened my query using `$accessapp.DoCmd.OpenQuery("MyQuery")` and I can see that it is loaded using `$accessapp.CurrentData.AllQueries("MyQuery")`. I would like to use `$accessapp.DoCmd.OutputTo(acOutputQuery, "MyQuery",<acFormat>, <file>)`, but for some reason, I keep getting the error:

```
Unexpected token 'acOutputQuery' in expression or statement
```

Just running `$accessapp.DoCmd.OutputTo` shows that is what is expected:

```
void OutputTo (AcOutputObjectType, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, AcExportQuality)
```

Every resource I have seen, including the [Microsoft OutputTo documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa220433(v=office.11)) uses the `acOutputObjectType` in this manner, so I am completely stumped.

Comment: Try using the constant's value (1) instead of its name.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response Hans! I'm not quite sure what you mean by this, though. Do you mean that the options are enumerated?

Comment: Change `$accessapp.DoCmd.OutputTo(acOutputQuery, "MyQuery",` to `$accessapp.DoCmd.OutputTo(1, "MyQuery",`  Does the problem go away when you make that change?

Comment: Yes, [AcOutputObjectType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acoutputobjecttype)

Comment: Thank you sir, this is the solution to my problem. Also, they `acFormat` enumeration needs to be used, but it uses a text key rather than a numeric one (i.e `acFormatTXT` needs to be `'MD-DOS'`. [MS Constants Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-12//bb226001(v=office.12)). If you don't post an answer by the time I get off work, I will do so myself, thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, sorry it took me a while to get back. Thanks to @HansUp for leading me down the correct path. I Used the [AcOutputObjectType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acoutputobjecttype)  link he posted as well as the [MS Constants Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-12//bb226001(v=office.12)). I'll give both a powershell example and an MS JScript one. I'll use `acOutputQuery` and `xcFormatTXT` as `1` and `"MS-DOS"` respectively here, but there are many others in the two links above.

powershell:

```
$acc = New-Object -com Access.Application

$acc.OpenCurrentDatabase("<path_to_file>.accdb")

$acc.DoCmd.OpenQuery("MyQuery")

$acc.DoCmd.OutputTo(1,"MyQuery","MS-DOS", "<path_to_output_file>.txt")
```

MS JScript:

```
function writeToTextFile(dbPath,queryName,outputPath){

    var acc = new ActiveXObject("Access.Application"); //create new COM instance
    acc.OpenCurrentDatabase(dbPath+".accdb"); //open the database
    if(!acc.CurrentData.AllQueries(queryName).IsLoaded){
        acc.DoCmd.OpenQuery(queryName); //load the query if it is not loaded yet
    }

    acc.DoCmd.OutputTo(1,queryName,"MS-DOS",outputPath+".txt"); //write to file

}
```

These two are kind of quick and dirty. Since I have this working in JScript now, I will probably make a `writeToFile()` function that takes the format as an argument. I considered using an object to map the name string to the enumeration, but I don't know how useful that would actually be. I suppose if you wanted, you could take the output object as an argument, too, but I only plan to use query objects for now.

Comment: Nice one! The answer made my day! Thanks!